# How to get item count along with total count with a single query in sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.2

I have a table that stores information about items sold across all locations by a sweet shop. It sells pastries, waffles, ice creams, candies etc.

I need to get this information from the table.

> Which item was sold the most per location along with total items sold in those locations.

Below is the structure of the table

```
     Column     |            Type             | Modifiers 
----------------+-----------------------------+-----------
 id             | integer                     | 
 date           | timestamp without time zone | 
 item           | character varying(15)       | 
 location       | character varying(25)       |
```

Now I break it down into two separate questions

1. Which item was sold the most per location
2. Total count of items sold per location.

These are my queries:

Query #1:

```
select location, item, count(item) as count_ 
from sweet_shop 
group by location, item;
```

Query #2:

```
select location, count(item) as count_ 
from sweet_shop 
group by location;
```

As you can see, I make two separate queries and then I need to map these two information to correct locations and get the final output. I am looking for an output like below

```
  location     |  item             | item_count    total_count 
---------------+-------------------+-------------|----------
 BA2           | candies           |   400       |     550
 BA4           | pastries          |   320       |     610 
 BA3           | waffles           |   250       |     400 
 BA7           | ice creams        |   180       |     500
```

But I want to get this information in a single query as opposed to making two separate queries. How can this be done?

**NOTE:** I am using Postgres 9.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would aggregate by location and item, using `COUNT()` as an analytic function to generate the total count per location.  Also, use `ROW_NUMBER` to identify the top performing item in each location.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT location, item, COUNT(*) AS item_count,
           SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY location) AS total_count,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY location
                              ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rn
    FROM sweet_shop
    GROUP BY location, item
)

SELECT location, item, item_count, total_count
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Postgres has a very nice extension `DISTINCT ON`, that allows you to do this without subqueries:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (location) location item,
       COUNT(*) AS item_count,
       SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY location) AS total_count
FROM sweet_shop
GROUP BY location, item
ORDER BY location, COUNT(*) DESC;
```

`DISTINCT ON` return the first row of a group of rows with the same key, where "first" is defined by the `ORDER BY` clause.